# Italian Street Address Validation with PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation, street-address

I need to validate an Italian address using **PHP** and **regex**. 
I have to write it like this:

```
Via/Corso (meaning street)/Viale (boulevard)/Piazza (square) [road] (,) [civic number], [city] ([abbreviation of province]).
```

An example is:

- *Via Garibaldi 374, Torino (TO)*
- *Piazza San Pietro, 325, Cerveteri (RM)*

---

I found, in a previous post, the solution for a complete Australian address but I don't know how to change it.
Here is the code and an example of an address that is considered valid:

*(15 Gordon St, 3121 Cremorne, Australia)*

```
if(!(preg_match('/^(?:\\d+ [a-zA-Z ]+, ){2}[a-zA-Z ]+$/', trim($_POST["via"])))){
    $via_err = "This street is invalid, insert #, Street name, Zip Code, City, Country.";
} else
    $via = trim($_POST["via"]);
```

Thanks to everyone who can help me with this problem.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That's [not very good](https://regex101.com/r/fNx2Kj/1)

Comment: @horcrux Ah, I see. I will remove the comment.

Comment: Be careful using regex for parsing addresses. You really should use an address validation service/API. [This explains](https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses) why parsing addresses with regex can be bad. (Disclaimer: I currently work for SmartyStreets, an address validation company)

Comment: I don't know if this is needed for some kind of addresses database already normalized to only contains addresses with "Via", "Piazza", etc, but in real life it would never work. There are a tons of other way to call a street in Italy. For example check Alzaia Naviglio Grande in Milan. Sure, the majority of addresses use the words you are asking for, but that is not enough in a real life application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this, just make sure to run it with the `i` flag to make it case-insensitive:

`(via|corso|viale|piazza) ([a-zA-Z ]+?),? (\d+), (\w+) \((\w+)\)`

The main tricky bit is the first switch, which is a bit messy because of how many types of streets there are. I just noticed you don't actually need the groups, so apart from the first set of parentheses, you could get rid of them:

`(via|corso|viale|piazza) [a-zA-Z ]+?,? \d+, \w+ \(\w+\)`

They won't hurt though, if you ever want to extract them.